# Parsing HTML with PHP and get values by using cycle

Tags: php, parsing

I have HTML structure like this

```
 <div class = article-comments>
  <div class="article-comment">
     <div class="article-comment-header">...</div>
     <div class="article-comment-content">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="article-comment">
     <div class="article-comment-header">...</div>
     <div class="article-comment-content">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
.
.
.
</div>
```

I have one div element - *comments* which contains many other div elements- *comment*. I need to get *header* element, which contains comment creator name,  and *content, which contains the comment.  I have code in PHP like this:

```
foreach($bot->parseBetweenRegexArray($data, '<div.*class="article-comment-content">', '<\/div>') as $commentary ){ 

   printf("comment: %s",$commentary); 

foreach($bot->parseBetweenRegexArray($data, '<div.*class="article-comment-header">', '<\/div>') as $name)  {

   printf("name: %s",$name); '<br />';
                            }
 }
```

But with this code I can't get correct order, like comment author name and corresponding comment and so on.
How to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't parse HTML with regex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/140925

Comment: If so, than, how can I get value of theese HTML div attributes correctly by using cycle?

Comment: I don't know about cycle, but I would look for a DOM or a SAX parser.

Comment: foreach($html->find('div.article-comments') as $article) {
     ?
       }.......

how to do this with DOM parser?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to use DOM (and don't want to use Regex with HTML), you can try to `explode` the HTML text with `<div class="article-comment-header">` string.

The very first element (index 0) of the result array will be useless (it's all before the first `<div>`, so start looping from the second (index 1).

Then explode the 2nd element with `</div>`. The very first element of the second array is the header.

Then do the something similiar to get the author.

Hint: PHP [`explode()`](http://php.net/EXPLODE) function provides additional argument `$limit` allowing you to separate text to only two pieces.

I agree this is not the best solution, but I think quite simple. I'd rather use some XML class to find it.